# App Crashing Upon Game Center Authentication

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, game-center

I seem to be at a loss here. When I open my app, and the Game Center app is logged out, my app crashes, but when Game Center is logged in, it works just fine. Here is the code I am using. Am I doing something wrong?

```
[[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error == nil) {
            // Insert code here to handle a successful authentication.
            //gcSuccess = YES;
        }
        else
        {
            // Your application can process the error parameter to report the error to the player.
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Could not connect with Game Center servers." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Try Later" otherButtonTitles:nil];
             [alert show];
        }
    }];
```

Also, here is the only error I see when the app crashes, and I only see this in the console, not in the run log.

```
Aug  1 20:15:08 Zachary-Christopouloss-iPhone backboardd[52] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 23: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
```

Any help on this would be awesome. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I *believe* you are supposed to check `[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].isAuthenticated` prior to authenticating... this shouldn't affect it, but perhaps there's some init that happens in there that gets angry if you skip it?

Comment: The error would imply a connection issue of some kind, don't know what BK would be that would be the origin. Are you seeing this in simulator or device, or both, and what OS version?

Comment: Both. iPhone on iOS6b3. Simulator on iOS5.1.

Comment: Hmm, which XCode version? Might be worth posting on the official apple forums, sounds like a bug in the kit or possibly a bad install to me, but no hard basis for that theory.

Comment: Xcode 4.4. It looks like it works fine with the iOS 6 SDK, but we cant really use that yet. Let me see if it happens on the iOS 5 SDK.

Comment: Looks like the iOS 5 SDK isn't installed and I cant figure out how to -.-

Comment: Sounds like you've gotten a busted XCode and SDK in some capacity. I would recommend re-installing.

Comment: Just reinstalled and I am still getting the same issue.